# Reload UITableView data and scroll down to last selected cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a long list of data to show in a `UITableView`. One cell of the table contains many things like comments, share and like. Now when user likes a post in the cell it `reloadTableData` and move to the first one again.
For example user have scrolled down to 30 cells and then like 29th cell, it'll reload the data and goes to the top again.
So how to make it stays at the same place after reloading the data? Here is my code:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return imagesArr.count;
}
```

And for the implmemtation of Like button

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
HomeCell *cellObj = (HomeCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"HomeCell" ];
cellObj.likeBtn.tag=indexPath.row;
[cellObj.likeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(loveButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return cellObj;
    }
```

`loveButtonClicked` button clicked.

```
-(void)loveButtonClicked
{
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:nil, nil];
    [[RRDataAcessLayer sharedDataAccessLayerManager]sendRequestToFetchHomeData:dict];
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
   // hud.labelText = @"Loading Data";

}
```

Image below will give you an idea. two cells are given and when the heart icon is tapped it reloads to update the value of total love.
[image: image of app]

Comment: add your code please

Comment: @hasan83 check my updated question.

Comment: add loveButtonClicked code

Comment: If my suggestion worked for you kindly accept my answer also for others to help .. Thanks

Comment: i made a demo application for you share me your email i will send you

Answer (score 2):

- Saved edited index in variable
- Get indexpath for that index
- Scroll to table after reoladdata to that index

> ```
> NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:editedRowNumber inSection:0];
>     [self.tableViewTimeline scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
> ```

- If your table view has one section you can pass zero if has number of section you have to pass section in which user edit cell

in like button action you can reload cell without scrolling by using both ways while best just reload selected index as suggest @Mhesh

```
    int selectedIndex=(int) btn.tag;
    int likes = [[self.arrayDataSource objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] intValue]+1;
    [self.arrayDataSource replaceObjectAtIndex:selectedIndex withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",likes]];
    NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:0];
    /*
    [self.refWeakTableView reloadData];
    [self.refWeakTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
     */
    [self.refWeakTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ip]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

and cell for row method set like button tag

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyTableViewCell";

    myTableViewCell *cell = (myTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    //    DataSourceModel* dbObject = (DataSourceModel*)[self.arrayDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.myCellLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.arrayDataSource[indexPath.row]];
    int indexed = (int)indexPath.row;

    cell.btnLike.tag = indexed;


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: that may solve the problem. but, it shouldn't exist in first place. the tableview should maintain its scroll position. that's the default behaviour on iOS

Comment: then you can use scrollPosition option UITableViewScrollPositionNone

Answer (score 1):

If action is like affected to one cell then why you reload the whole table, reload the only single cell using below code

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPathOfYourCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

You can change `UITableViewRowAnimation`.

Comment: this seems logical. Let me give it a try.

Comment: Have you used facebook app? Then how did facebook do this when you like something? The solution you provided might work but there is a lot going on in the app that I can't figure out where to put this code. Because in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'm not reloading the data.

Comment: when you like the button and it call function in this function you have to find the indexpath of tableview according to touched like button then write your all logic and at the end of the function write the above code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to cache the current selection in didSelectedCellAtIndexPath in your Controller and if you reload the whole table you could scroll to this last cached indexPath with the tableView's methods for scrolling. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not reload all table data, but only the rows you want. You can do this by calling this method on tableView  [reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_:withRowAnimation:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)
It will reload only desired cells with a desired animation without scrolling to top of table view